# How to bind one column to gridview which is not present in database

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server-2005, gridview, devexpress

How to bind one column to the gridview which is not present in the database?

I want to display the total unit in the last column named `Total Unit` but it is not present in database.

I got an argument exception:

> Column 'tunit' does not belong to
>   table.

```
foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows )
{
   object[] obj=new object[2];
   obj[0] = row["Transaction_Id"];
   obj[1] = row["tunit"];
   dtgrid.Rows.Add(obj);
}
```

Comment: There are a couple of solutions I can think of for this but I'll be able to give the most suitable if you provide a little more detail, and maybe a code snippet.  Are you binding to a DataTable?  Are you manually adding the columns on the grid view or are they auto generated?

Answer (score 3):

The best solution to this problem is to implement unbound column as it is explained in the [Unbound Columns](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/CustomDocument3732) topic.

Answer (score 0):

if you are binding a list, you can add a property to that list and bind to the grid using eval("PropertyName")

Answer (score 0):

When you prepare the select query make sure you have one more extra column with the total value you want for that particular row, then you can specify a column in the gridview as follows, make sure you specify

```
'AutoGenerateColumns = false;
```

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="sds_datasourceName">  
<Columns>   
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Total" >
                <itemtemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Total" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Total") %>'></asp:Label>
                </itemtemplate>

            </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```